# LyX footnote in table minipage not working after upgrade

Tags: tables, lyx, footnotes, minipage

I had tables with footnotes that were placed below the table using Minipage boxing, as described in  [the wiki](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Tables#footintab). The document compiled well using an older LyX version (2.2.?, not sure). But after upgrading to version 2.3.0 the footnotes are sent to the bottom of the page and the Minipage seems to have no effect. What should I do to get the previous behavior?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wXiQcQM7cOnjXZc2Fad5eI7te5UMUInX)  is an example file.
 [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fNKukckeekt8UhSJR1dMa4-mH80S0uFe)  is the output.

Thank you.

Comment: The google drive links appear to be protected.

Comment: I can confirm that the PDF will look as expected with 2.3.1 (I just tested your .lyx file with the LyX version that will be developed into 2.3.1).

Answer (score 1):

This will be [changed](http://www.lyx.org/trac/changeset/6810a181/lyxgit) back to the previous behavior in LyX 2.3.1, which should be released within the next couple of weeks. To get the old behavior back with LyX 2.3.0, you can add the following to the preamble (Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble):

```
\renewcommand{\tablefootnote}{\footnote}
```

as [noted](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=mid&q=8346c9d9-c29b-bb63-d438-3bc56d9331f7%40gmail.com) by Paul Rubin.

Comment: This worked for 2.3.0, thank you. Will I have to remove the line from the preamble after upgrade to  2.3.1 or later versions?

Comment: @farshadnia yes you should